# Issues sharing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, I've got these functions running on click:

```
$('#bodyHVAC a#zMaps').one('click', function(){
    appendZoneMapStuff(globalPaths.mallName, function(){
        //console.log('appendZoneMapStuff');
        setTimeout(function(){
            getPathToUnits(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    setupRoof('roofMrtu', function(){
                        //console.log('setupRoof');
                    });
                }, 500);
            });
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

I set it up this way so that the functions would run one after another, but they don't seem to always be doing that.

I've got this global variable:

```
var AMnamePathObj = {};
```

For simplicity, lets say the code of getPathToUnits() is:

```
function getPathToUnits(callback){
    AMnamePathObj = {lookin: "good"};
    console.log(AMnamePathObj);
    if (callback)
        callback();
}
```

And the code for setupRoof() is:

```
function setupRoof(){
    console.log(AMnamePathObj);
    if (callback)
        callback();
}
```

But I am getting [object object] when the console.log in setupRoof() runs, even though AMnamePathObj is a global variable! I don't even want to be using AMnamePathObj as a global variable but I don't know how else to pass the info of AMnamePathObj to the other function.

Comment: A timeout seems to be missing here.

Comment: is it that `one` = `on`?

Comment: instead of using a global var you could store `AMnamePathObj.lookin` as a custom html5 `data-` attribute in your DOM. use jquery if you don't want to clutter your dom, it has a similar concept independent of the dom.

Comment: Looks to me like you want to use promise. http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: @dystroy it just acts as 0 if there is no timeout, but I've added the 0 in now.

Comment: try `console.dir(AMnamePathObj);`

Comment: @JohnBoker Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about console.dir, but it didn't really work, cuz it says it has no properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[object Object] is the default string representation of an object in JavaScript.  If you were expecting a useful description of AMnamePathObj you should give it a toString function e.g. :

```
var foo = {
  name: "Steve",
  toString: function() {
     return this.name;
  }
};
console.debug(""+foo);
```

Compare with :

```
console.debug(""+{});
```

So nothing wrong with being able to see the variable in question.

Comment: Why would the first console.log print as Object {lookin: "good"} and the next one as [Object Object]?

Comment: Ah that was not apparent from your question. However given the code you posted there is no way that setupRoof could be called before getPathToUnits

Comment: Note that another thing you can try is e.g. window.__AMNamePAthObj = AMNamePathObj in one function and then in the other where it appears to have changed you can test whether AMNamePathObj === window.__AMNamePathObj, as it seems it must be getting assigned to a different object from what you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was that on the second cosole.log() was AMnamePathObj + 'dude' not just AMnamePathObj. Should have been obvious, thanks though.